# Is it possible to create a widget using Xamarin.Forms?

Tags: xamarin, xamarin.forms, xamarin.android, xamarin.ios, widget

I want to add a widget to an existing app using existing XAML views. For example i have a project which is called QuizApp. And this project has three main solution such as

1. **QuizApp**
2. **QuizApp.Android**
3. **QuizApp.ios**

As you can guess if you add some sourcecode into the QuizApp . It works for both side (Android and ios).That is why i want to add widget for my application by using QuizApp solution . Nevertheless i did some research and i couldn't find out a way to create widget from inside QuizApp solution. If I create widget in QuizzApp.Android and QuizzApp.ios .This project is going to be useless for me . What should i have to do ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'm afraid it is not possible create a widget for the Cross platform part of xamarin On a Specific platform yes [Link](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/samples/xamarin/monodroid-samples/simplewidget/)

Comment: Is there an equivalent to a widget in iOS?